# Scrape table html multipage with beautifulsoup4 and urllib3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape, urllib3

Help me please,,
the code I made only works for 1 page, I want it for all pages. what should I do?

```
import csv 
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


outfile = open("data.csv","w",newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)


    for i in range(1,20) :
            url = f'http://ciumi.com/cspos/barcode-ritel.php?page={i}'
            req = urllib3.PoolManager()
            res = req.request('GET', url)
            tree = BeautifulSoup(res.data, 'html.parser')  
            table_tag = tree.select("table")[0]
    tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                    for row_data in table_tag.select("tr")]

    for data in tab_data:
        writer.writerow(data)
        print( res, url, ' '.join(data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working well, if you want to **scrape** all the uri and get data from them you just have to correctly indent it:

```
import csv
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


outfile = open("data.csv","w",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for i in range(1,20) :
    url = f'http://ciumi.com/cspos/barcode-ritel.php?page={i}'
    req = urllib3.PoolManager()
    res = req.request('GET', url)
    tree = BeautifulSoup(res.data, 'html.parser')
    table_tag = tree.select("table")[0]
    tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")] for row_data in table_tag.select("tr")]
    for data in tab_data:
        writer.writerow(data)
        print( res, url, ' '.join(data))
```

But you have to clean the data to have a pretty csv file

Comment: Hello maaz, thank you. my code has been going well.

how to clean CSV data ? because I get duplicate data